# How do I add Elements to an array in useReducer that is generic type in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

Am looking into old code & I have a generic reducer that handles fetching off data and the initial state looks like this

```
 const initialState: State<T> = {
    status: STATUS.INIT,
    data: undefined,
    error: undefined,
  }
```

Since I don't know what type the value is going to be beforehand data `undefined`

```
  const fetchReducer = (state: State<T>, action: Action<T>): State<T> => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ACTION_TYPE.REQUEST:
        return { ...initialState, status: STATUS.FETCHING }
      case ACTION_TYPE.SUCCESS:
        return { ...initialState, status: STATUS.FETCHED, data: action.payload }
      case ACTION_TYPE.FAILURE:
        return { ...initialState, status: STATUS.ERROR, error: action.payload }
      default:
        return state
    }
```

then here we have the reducer handling data. I am encountering a problem though, I need to add a array of data without removing the old. How do I change the type `ACTION_TYPE.SUCCESS`. What should I do to chnage it to allow it?

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You start out by saying _"I have a generic reducer"_, yet now you want to make the assumption that `T` is an array type. Array concatenation will be better handled in a different reducer than this, one in which you can safely assume `T extends any[]`.

Comment: How can one hook handle multiple reducers?

Comment: One hook does not handle multiple reducers. The approach I'm suggesting is to separate the concerns of fetching and state; use two reducers, and a `useEffect()` to concatenate data fetching results into your array state